# Convert OR to And Condition on array values in LINQ c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a linq query which is working as OR on Array or list of IDs. here is the Code:

Right now, the below code is working as if any tutor has Subject1 or Subject2, it will the list if either tutor has one of them, i want to get records or tutor list who has both of them.

```
query = query.Where(x => x.TutorSubjects.Any(q => q.SubjectId.HasValue && filter.Subjects.Contains(q.SubjectId.Value)));
```

I want to convert it to "And" Condition, it should work like if the list and all the ids specified in Filter.Subjects.

I tried to add few examples given on Google but i didn't get expected result. i'm beginner in LINQ and EF. Please help me.

Not sure if Contains is going to work as it is mentioned on Google on few articles.

Comment: @downvoters please leave your comments

Comment: What or condition? i don't see it

Comment: @GlennvanAcker, i updated the Question please have a look

Comment: It's not possible to find out what are you trying to achieve. It would be better to provide you DB schema and desired sql query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all):

```
query = query.Where(x => x.TutorSubjects.All(q => q.SubjectId.HasValue && filter.Subjects.Contains(q.SubjectId.Value)));
```

Comment: It is checking as IN query, but i want to get "AND"

Comment: @RamSingh, Step one [ASK], Step 2 [mre]. Step 3 produce a list of few simple customclass with few properties. That will be equivalent of your db thing. Step 4 produce a list of element equivalent to your filter thing. If peter cristal ball  failed please clarify the question.

Comment: @RamSingh Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59175806/edit) the question and give data samples for which it should produce a match, along with data samples for which it should not produce a match, along with the reason why in both cases.